# Rails association callback with cached query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models:

```
class Basket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products

  def recalculate_price!
    price = products.map(&:price).sum
    save
  end
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :basket

  after_save :update_basket

  def update_basket
    basket.recalculate_price!
  end
end
```

and than I call it like this:

```
basket = Basket.new
basket.products.build(price)
basket.save
```

The problem: `basket.price` don't update.

I've investigated the problem and found out that there is some kind of caching in `update_basket` method. The problem could be solved with placing `reload` before `basket.recalculate_price!`.

Is there any option to leave the `update_basket` method untouched? I have many such cases in my application.

I would like to understand how it works and avoid similar problems in the future.

note: I recently upgraded rails from 3.2 to 4.2. In a previous version everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any option to leave the update_basket method untouched?

Absolutely. You can place a condition on your `after_create` to avoid executing it some times:

```
after_save :update_basket if: :basked_should_be_updated

[...]

private

def basked_should_be_updated
  [...]
  # return true or false in here
end
```

Comment: You didn't addressed the main problem: why `basket.price` don't update and how to fix it